# Powershell unable to rename SharePoint 2019 file if missing a file extension

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have what I thought would be a simple script.  I have a library with a number of files that are missing a .pdf extension, due to a script that ran and generated them.  I wrote a script to rename them, and it works if the existing file has an extension.  If the extension is missing, PowerShell does nothing to the name.

Below is a sample that I stripped down to a basic single file rename.  This won't work if the file extension doesn't exist on the target file.

Has anyone seen this before and know how to work around it?

```
    $web = get-spweb "https://sp.domain.com/sites/somesite"
$docs = $web.Lists["DocTest"]
foreach($doc in $docs.items){
    Write-Host $doc["Name"]
    if($doc.Name -eq "test"){
        $new = 'test.pdf'
        $doc["Name"] = $new
        $doc.update()
        Write-Host $doc["Name"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to work around this by mapping the document library to a drive and using get-childitem and rename-item.  I would still like to know why the original code didn't work though.

Comment: Hi K J.  The issue I am having is renaming the file, so I wouldn't be able to rename it as "test." either.  Thx.

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying now.  I did just try that, but unfortunately the file name stayed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to get the file from the item and then use the MoveTo function to rename it. Try this:

```
$web = get-spweb "https://sp.domain.com/sites/somesite"
$docs = $web.Lists["DocTest"]
foreach($doc in $docs.items){
    Write-Host $doc["Name"]
    if($doc.Name -eq "test"){
        $new = 'test.pdf'
        $file = $doc.File
        $file.MoveTo($doc.ParentList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + $new)
        $file.Update()
        Write-Host $doc["Name"]
    }
}
```

Comment: That Gaurav T!  I was surprised that this worked.  I thought for sure it would do something to the version history.  Not only did it leave the version history, but it updated the version that was current.  The only change I detected was that I used a different account to run the script and that changed the Modified By (and Modified) field in the current version.  Kudos on this one!! Thanks.